# How to use an Sqlite database in a memory mapped drive which is asynchronously backed up?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, memory

I have a c# API app (.Net v8) in which I want to use an Sqlite memory database (for speed, obviously) for SQL operations, but this is limited to accesses by a single process.

So I propose to create the database file in a memory-mapped drive, which will then allow access to it by multiple processes, right?

But ideally I would also like updates to it to be continuously backed up in a "fire and forget" async mode, to keep a roughly up-to-date copy on disk.

(I know a disk based memory mapped file is backed up to disk when the final connection is closed. But I was rather hoping for a more continuous backup, in case the app crashes.)

This all seems a requirement which would very often be required by others; but it is hard to find any existing code examples which even vaguely approximate it!

The nearest I have found was from years ago, and I would be content to copy that if I could be sure the methods etc have not changed considerably in the years since 2011 when it was written:

https://web.archive.org/web/20130326111615/http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com:80/forums/t/2403.aspx

P.S. Answers along the lines of "This is the wrong thing to want to do" will NOT be helpful! I am confident it is the correct solution for my requirements, and am frankly amazed that there don't seem to be any existing code examples (which is what I am looking for) already.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77645885/is-there-a-c-sharp-library-for-using-an-sqlite-database-in-a-memory-mapped-drive - you've simply reposted the same question with a minor title change; why do you expect a different outcome this time? why not fix the original?

Comment: @Marc The original question was closed (whether by a person or bot I don't know) because it asked for something which is not allowed. (I dare not mention what this was, in case that prompts the question to be closed again!) Also, I should point out that even in the few seconds the original question was visible someone kindly replied to mention the "VACUUM FROM" Sqlite facility, so that is worth knowing.

Comment: It was closed for a reason. Yes, what you ask is wrong, which is why people don't do it. SQLite is an embedded database. It's *built* for single-process use. If people want multi-process access they use different databases

Comment: SQLite itself allows multiple writers if you use [Write-ahead logging](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) mode. Updates won't appear until checkpointing though. So part of what you ask already exists. If you want replication, which is most definitely *not* a multi-process access mechanism, you can use [LiteFS](https://github.com/superfly/litefs) to copy the WAL entries to other locations

Comment: So for `amazed that there don't seem to be any existing code examples`, there *are* a lot of examples and documentation already. They don't look like what you expected though.

Comment: What you're looking for is functionality found in *desktop databases* like MS Access, or FireBird with databases stored eg on a network drive that are shared by multiple users. That's *very* different from both embedded and server-based databases which own their own files. There's not a lot of interest in that space though. Either people use embedded databases and sync data outside them (mobile apps) or they set up a small server-based database.

Comment: @Panagiotis, if the same SQLite database can be used by multiple threads, why can't it be used by multiple processes (provided it is in shared memory, so these processes can all see it) ? Also, I mentioned SQLite only as an example, as it is readily available, but I wonder if there are other in-shared-memory databases which can be reliably used by multiple processes.

Comment: What you just described is what WAL mode already allows, BUT you'll have to account for stale data. As for `why can't it be used by multiple processes`, it has very little to do with how you access the file. You can easily open a file in share mode and read data from it already. You can't know if the data is *consistent* though. If multiple processes try to work with the same rows at the same time, how do you show valid data to all of them? Keep a list of row locks? Multiple row versions? Both options are complex and expensive

Comment: What SQLite chose to do instead is to store changes in a log and apply them back to the data files periodically - when a checkpoint is applied. The data files aren't locked in the meantime, which means other connections can keep reading data. This mechanism is a lot simpler and cheaper. In a multi-threaded application it's a lot easier to coordinate operations so threads don't end up using stale data.